# Override model method in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this in `config/initializers/my_app_model.rb`

```
module MyAppModel
  def test
    'test'
  end
end
ActiveRecord::Base.send :include, MyAppModel
```

And in `app/models/namespace/my_model.rb`

```
class Namespace::MyModel < Namespace
  def test
    'changed!'
  end
end
```

How can I make `test` to return `changed!`? It currently returns `test`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From some posts I [read](http://urbanautomaton.com/blog/2013/08/27/rails-autoloading-hell/), Rails loads models as they are asked, what I did was to make sure that model file was loaded just after initializer:

```
module MyAppModel
  def test
    'test'
  end
end
ActiveRecord::Base.send :include, MyAppModel

require Rails.root.join 'app/models/namespace/my_model'
```